# Bash if with subshell not running as expected

Tags: bash, if-statement, dhclient

I'm trying to automate **dhclient** release and new IPv4 new connection, When the connection is failing I usually do:

```
dhclient -r
dhclient -4
```

I created a script to automate this by pinging and running an if statement relative to the ping results.

```
#!/bin/bash

TEST=1;

while [[ $TEST -ne 0 ]]; do
    if [[ $(ping -c 5 "www.ubuntu.com") -ne 0 ]]; then
        dhclient -r;
        dhclient -4;

    else
        echo "Connection is good";
        TEST=0;
    fi
done
```

When I try to reverse the logic it doesn't say the connection is good but it goes and runs as false. Why is this?

```
#!/bin/bash

TEST=1;

while [[ $TEST -ne 0 ]]; do
    if [[ $(ping -c 5 "www.ubuntu.com") -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Connection is good";
        TEST=0;
    else
        dhclient -r;
        dhclient -4;
    fi
done
```

Comment: You're comparing *output*, not exit status -- but it's exit status that's 0 on success and nonzero otherwise.

Comment: For exit status it's just `if ping -c 5 www.ubuntu.com; then ...` -- no `$()` or `[[ ]]` or other syntax needed. Redirect stdout and stderr away if you don't want 'em.

Comment: And the reverse is `if ! ping ..; then ..`.

Comment: That works, I took out the brackets on both versions. You can post it as an answer.